# How to setText to total of all SeekBar progress values?

Tags: java, android, android-seekbar

I want "result.setText" to show the changing total of the accumulative progress of all of the SeekBars. I'm also trying to store that changing int to a variable of its own(equal to the total of all of the SeekBar's progress.)

I have 9 SeekBars, all of them have a max of 3. When I change any one of them up I want totalScoreInt to equal +1. If I were to move each SeekBar up one from 0, one at a time, I would want TotalScoreInt to grow by 1, from 0 to 27 and the TotalScoreInt would shrink by 1 from 27 to 0 if I were to do the opposite from each at their max.

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

    seekBar1value = progress;
    seekBar2value = progress;
    seekBar3value = progress;
    seekBar4value = progress;
    seekBar5value = progress;
    seekBar6value = progress;
    seekBar7value = progress;
    seekBar8value = progress;
    seekBar9value = progress;

    totalScoreInt =
            (seekBar1value
                    + seekBar2value
                    + seekBar3value
                    + seekBar4value
                    + seekBar5value
                    + seekBar6value
                    + seekBar7value
                    + seekBar8value
                    + seekBar9value);

    switch (seekBar.getId()){
        case R.id.seekBar1:
            result.setText("Score: " +progress);
            break;

        case R.id.seekBar2:
            result.setText("Score: " +progress);
            break;

        case R.id.seekBar3:
            result.setText("Score: " +progress);
            break;

        case R.id.seekBar4:
            result.setText("Score: " +progress);
            break;

        case R.id.seekBar5:
            result.setText("Score: " +progress);
            break;

        case R.id.seekBar6:
            result.setText("Score: " +progress);
            break;

        case R.id.seekBar7:
            result.setText("Score: " +progress);
            break;

        case R.id.seekBar8:
            result.setText("Score: " +progress);
            break;

        case R.id.seekBar9:
            result.setText("Score: " +progress);
            break;
    }

    //result.setText(String.valueOf("Score: " +totalScoreInt));
}
```

This code sets the text to whatever the last changed SeekBar progress value was at.

I want that number to grow or shrink each time change any of the SeekBars progress.

So if seekBar1 progress = 3 and seekBar2 progress = 2 totalScoreInt would equal 5 and that would be set in "result"

Comment: It's unclear what the question is. Please provide more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to keep a global reference for each and every `SeekBar`, alongside with your counter variable. Then, create a method somewhat like this:

```
private int progress;

private SeekBar sb1, sb2, sb3; // And the others...

private synchronized void handleSeekBars() {
    progress = sb1.getProgress() + sb2.getProgress() + sb3.getProgress();
}
```

And then, call it inside each `SeekBar#OnSeekBarChangeListener()`, like this:

```
sb1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
        handleSeekBars();
        result.setText("Score: " + progress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
});
```

That should do the trick.